# How to convert ascii char to int like c/c++ in rust

Tags: rust

In c/c++, an ascii char can be converted to a number

`int('a')`

But how to do this in rust?

Comment: convert like this `'a' as u32` and the way back [`char::from_u32()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_u32.html)

Comment: For a safer method, you can use `u32::from` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert character to `u32` this way: `let code = 'a' as u32;`. This will give you unicode value for specific character.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "0123";
    for c in s.chars() {
        println!("{c} -> {}", c as u32);
    }
}
```

[Try it here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ee05994c953197e32e1321df2e928a2)

But if you are strictly require to work with ASCII not with Unicode, you can also check [ascii crate](https://docs.rs/ascii/latest/ascii/)

Comment: Code just works with unicodes. Edition includes a 3rd party. The language already has built in solutions.

Comment: Better to use `u32::from(c)`.